# How to change colour automatically with size?

Tags: color, gimp, automation

Is there a way in GIMP to automatically associate a colour with a given brush size? The use case is that large objects are typically in the foreground, and should in general have a lighter tone than background (smaller) objects.

I'd like Gimp to associate **color** with a brush **size**. That is all.

A larger *size* should result in a lighter *color* (that's one algorithm; there are infinitely more).

I am **not** asking for an AI to decide what's in the foreground and what's in the background; I'm just saying that the way I paint is that large things go into the foreground and are lighter in tone.

The *decision*, therefore, is made by the human, but the automation is done by the software.

Comment: How on earth would a standard image editor know what is or is not in the foreground/background? All it sees are pixels. And how would it know *what* area you may be focusing on or even if the photo is of a nature to *have* a foreground/background? It's often the case that a small brush is used to touchup content in any foreground or a large brush is used to alter a background. There's no correlation between pixels, spacial placement, and brush size.

Comment: Hmmm... let me try and clarify :-) I'd like GIMP to associate COLOUR with a brush SIZE. That is all. A larger SIZE should result in a lighter COLOUR (that's one algorithm; there are infinitely more).  I am *NOT* asking for an AI to decide what's in the foreground and what's in the background; I'm just saying that the way I paint is that large things go into the foreground and are lighter in tone. The decision, therefore, is made by the human, but the automation is done by the software. Does that make more sense? :-)

Comment: Clarifications should be added to the question. There is an [edit] button, just for that.

Answer (score 1):

In drawing and painting generally, distant objects in the background are usually fainter/lighter, but more vivid/darker in the foreground. The technique is called [colour perspective](http://www.exploring-landscape-painting.com/colour-perspective.html)

You can create custom colour brushes in GIMP where the colour is fixed to the brush (but not specifically to its size).  Basically, you export an rgb coloured image (with a transparent background) as a .gbr brush in your GIMP Brushes folder, rather than the usual greyscale image.  There are tutorials online for creating custom brushes in GIMP.  So, you could potentially create different sized brushes for each colour you want.  However, it's not a very practical solution. To use them at their intended size, you'd need to reset the size in the brush tool options each time you choose a different brush.  It's probably more trouble than it's worth.

It would probably be much easier to just use regular brushes, set up a custom colour palette with the range of colours you want, and select the colours you want as you paint.

Another way to proceed might be to have your content on different layers, for example a layer for foreground objects, for objects in the middle distance, and for objects in the background. Then afterwards you could apply colour adjustments to those layers, using Curves, or perhaps Brightness-Contrast adjustments.